# objective-c equivalent for AS3's Shape class

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3, shapes

I have been banging my head on this for hours. What would be the equivalent of AS3's `Shape` class in Objective C? Is it a UIView?

I am trying to get a bitmapfill with custom paths out of an image. In flash it is as simple as:

```
var mesh:Shape = new Shape();
mesh.graphics.beginBitmapFill(new MeshBitmapData(), null, true, false);
mesh.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
mesh.graphics.endFill();
```

Is there an equivalent in Objective C? Or am I missing something all together?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html). It uses basic drawing principles similar to AS3, but no 
automatic shape creations as far as I know. You may want to look around for libraries though if that is the case.

**EDIT**

I found [this](http://clickflickboom.com/drawing-in-objective-c-lines-and-circles/) tutorial which may help you out.